# Reflection: invoke a method using Number as wrapper for premitives

Tags: java, reflection, primitive-types

My task is to call the methods of java.lang.Math using a String with the necessary information. Since there are only methods using primitive number types I use Number as a wrapper, which then gets the value parsed from String.

```
Number value = null;
    switch (attributClass) {
        [...]//parse the attribute into "value"
    }
Method m = null;
try{
    m = Class.forName("java.lang.Math").getDeclaredMethod(mName, value.getClass());
...
```

now my problem is that I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Math.acos(java.lang.Double)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)

I suppose this happens because Double is not the primitive type double but is there any way to get the primitive from the Number?

Comment: You can use double.class or int.class or what ever primitive you want

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard method for converting wrapper classes to primitive classes an vice versa to my knowledge.

A hacky way to get the primitive class of a wrapper class is `wrapperClass.getDeclaredField("TYPE").get(null)` (Because each wrapper defines such a field). If you don't want to do that you can create a `Map<Class, Class>` to map from wrappers to primitives and fill it with the 8 primitive types and their respective wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little less the obvious, but you can use `primitive.class`, for example

```
m = Class.forName("java.lang.Math").getDeclaredMethod("min", int.class, int.class);
```

Comment: yes but I can't do this using Number as wrapper and therefore I have to do this for every type that could be an argument for the method call, which I was trying to avoid